# add css to google maps v3 polylines?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

is there any way to customise google maps v3 polylines
I think the only options mentioned are strokecolor, weight and opacity 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#PolylineOptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only options to style Google's polyline are the ones presented in the documentation. There is no way to customize them further by default.

However, what might work is creating a custom polyline class where you can define everything you want, but this is connected to a lot of work. You would have to start by inheriting the `OverlayView` class and implement all the needed features (Maybe it does also work if you inherit `Polyline` and overwrite just the drawing methods - the problem is, you don't really know how the original source code looks like).

In fact, for Google Maps V2, Bill Chadwick did this. You can see a demonstration on his [website](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/BdccGmapBits.htm) (the dashed polyline example at the bottom). Maybe his implementation helps you to transfer it to Google Maps API V3.